# JavaScript: Enabling/ disabling "text input" according to the value selected from "select input"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote this piece of code to "disable" a text input if "Cash" payment selected from the select input. I also wanted to "enable" a text input if "Credit Card" payment selected. But I couldn't even get enabling done with JavaScript.

```
<input type="text" readonly="true" class="credit_card_number" id="inputWarning" name="credit_card_number"/>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="control-group">
<label for="payment_type" class="control-label"><i class="icon-book"></i> Payment Type</label>
<div class="controls">
<select size="1" id="payment_type" name="payment_type" onchange="enableElements();">
    <option value="cash" id="cash" selected="selected">Cash</option>
    <option value="amex" id="credit_card">American Express</option>
    <option value="master" id="credit_card">Master Card</option>
    <option value="visa" id="credit_card">Visa</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
function enableElements()
{
document.getElementById('inputWarning').disabled=false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try `$('#inputWarning').attr('disabled', 'false');`

Comment: Here is only one text input.

Comment: There's no need to involve jQuery for something so simple..

Comment: It's tagged with jQuery, anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jMThp/)**

This will work. But I would suggest changing from read only to attr:disabled, more clear for the user, I think. In that case check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dtF7y/).

Script/jQuery

```
function enableElements() {
if ($("#payment_type").val() == 'cash') {
    $("#inputWarning").prop('readonly', true);
    console.log('cash');
}

if ($("#payment_type").val() == 'amex' || $("#payment_type").val() == 'master' || $("#payment_type").val() == 'visa') {
   $("#inputWarning").prop('readonly', false);
    console.log('other');
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('inputWarning').disabled=""
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rKQjp/

The element gets disabled by setting the disabled attribute to "disabled" and it gets enabled again if you set this attribute to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
function enableElements()
{
    if($('#payment-type').val() == "cash"){
        $('#inputWarning').attr('disabled', 'true');
    }
    else $('#inputWarning').attr('disabled', 'false');
}
```

Comment: The question has a jquery tag, so I used jQuery.

Comment: I have seen many times that a lot of people who are just beginning to learn javascript use jQuery without even realising, that it's not pure javascript ;) I suppose that `@saucecord` may be one of them.

Comment: Honestly, I'm more into PHP and I only comes to JavaScript or jQuery whenever I need something beautiful like a date and time picker. So, apologies for my lack of knowledge in JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function enableElements()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("payment_type");
    var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if(str == 'Cash')
       document.getElementById('inputWarning').setAttribute("readonly", "true");
    else if(str == 'amex' || str == 'master' || str == 'visa')
       document.getElementById('inputWarning').setAttribute("readonly", "false");
}
```

NOTE: in question, same id is there for 3 options. Use different attribute to identify

using jQuery:

```
function enableElements()
{
    var str = $("#payment_type").val();
    if(str == 'Cash')
       $('#inputWarning').attr('readonly', true);
    else if(str == 'amex' || str == 'master' || str == 'visa')
       $('#inputWarning').removeAttr('readonly');
}
```

Comment: there is a read only attr in OP's input so it's not writable.

Comment: "NOTE: in question, same id is there for 3 options. Use different attribute to identify"

@Paritosh Sorry about that. Changed them to "class". I may have forgotten basics while playing with Twitter bootstrap. Fixed! :)

Comment: I think I might stick to @Sergio's solution. It worked in the first place. Now customizing it. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this script. I have used jquery. Make sure to add jquery lib.

```
<script>
function enableElements()
{
var type = $('#payment_type').val();
if(type == 'amex' || type == 'master' || type == 'visa')
{
   $("#inputWarning").attr("readonly", true);
}
else
{
   $("#inputWarning").attr("readonly", false);
}

</scrip
```